# Java Session Timeout - When I start the application for the first time, the session expired message gets displayed

Tags: java, xml, session, servlets

When I start the application for the first time, sessionExpired page gets called. Could anyone tell me how to prevent that from happening? Once it enters the application, it expires after the session times out like it is supposed to. I'm using tiles.xml.

tiles.xml

```
<!--Session Expired Page -->
    <definition name="sessionExpired" extends="login.definition">
        <put-attribute name="information" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/sessionExpired.jsp" />
    </definition>
<!--End of Session Expired Page -->
```

web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.Filter.SessionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

SessionFilter

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session != null) {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            long lastSessionAccessedTime = session.getLastAccessedTime() / 1000;
            int inactiveInterval = (int) currentTime -lastSessionAccessedTime);

            if (inactiveInterval > session.getMaxInactiveInterval()) {
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/sessionExpired");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        } else {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/sessionExpired");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The scenarios are the same - on startup or a new session - with session == null

On startup all the previous sessions are invalidated so you are getting sent to sessionExpired, the same as a new session

It depends on requirements - but you may want to look at persistent sessions on tomcat

Comment: Okay, I will look into persistent sessions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set 'somevalue' in minutes in web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        ${somevalue}
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: I have set it to 1 minute. But that is not the issue. I would like to know how to stop the sessionExpired page from displaying while starting the application.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting session expired page as below code would return null for expired session as well as for session not created at all.

> ```
>     HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
> ```

As no session is created when your application starts, it returns null.

I would suggest you to use separate logic for new session and expired session. One of the way to check expired session is:

> ```
>   if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null
>           && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
>       // Session is expired       
>   }
> ```

Something like below will avoid session expired page if request is new:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (session != null) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        long lastSessionAccessedTime = session.getLastAccessedTime() / 1000;
        int inactiveInterval = (int) currentTime -lastSessionAccessedTime);

        if (inactiveInterval > session.getMaxInactiveInterval()) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/sessionExpired");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    } else if(expiredSession(request)){
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/sessionExpired");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}

private boolean expiredSession(HttpServletRequest request){
      if (request.getRequestedSessionId() != null
              && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
          return true;
      }     
      return false;
}
```

Comment: While running the application for the first time, `request.getRequestedSessionId() != null
              && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` condition is true. So again it goes to the sessionExpired page instead of the login page.